# Flex and OOP customs for simple getters and setters

Tags: apache-flex, oop

I am having a little play with Flex and I'm curious as to a few things.

Firstly for my instance variables I can define something like

```
private var _count:int = 0;
```

It then seems that If I have a getter and setter for count e.g

```
        public function get count():int
    {
        return _count;
    }

    public function set count(value:int):void
    {
        _count = count;
    }
```

I can from within another function call something like

```
count++;
```

which in turn sets _count to increase by one.

I.E I can seemingly access count through count or _count because I have a getter and setter..

That is correct understanding?

For something like the above is good OOP practice to have the getter and setter or simply call `_count++;`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will point out that your set count method changes the variable _points.  If that is a typo, then:

Yes; that is a correct understanding. It sounds like your tests already proved that.

The private var _count will not be accessible by other classes with a reference to an instance of your class; but the public 'count' will be.

Getter and Setters are useful for performing other functionality within the class.  In the context of a Flex UI Component, you may dispatch an event, or invalidate the component through one of the Flex component invalidation methods.

Separating out the get and set methods also allow you to create properties that are read only, or properties that are write only, just by leaving out the respective get or set method.

IF that is not a typo; then I have no idea why count++ would change the _count variable at all; and something else is going on with the count that you haven't shown us.

Comment: It was a typo :P That is great - perfect answer. As I thought.

Comment: Another advantages of getters and setters is that they are the only way to declare properties on an Interface. And if you're at all concerned about good OOP, you should be coding to Interfaces most of the time. Setters also give you a "hook" so you can do something in response to a property change (for example, if you needed to add another visual object in a View because the count went up).

Comment: If you're worried about good OOP; interfaces should define functionality not data.  Adding get/set methods to an interface is a crutch.